# Add double quotes to a string in scala

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I have a string which looks like below

```
var str = [2020-01-01],[2020-01-02],[2020-01-03]
```

and the expected result is

```
var str = "2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03"
```

I tried replaceAll `replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")` but it is removing the square brackets but unable to figure out how to add the quotes.

What should I change to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do the same, by escaping the quotation mark with single escape slash:

```
str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "\"")
//Output "2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03"
```